# Pythons fastest way of randomising case of a string

Tags: python, string, variables, random

I want to randomise the case of a string, heres what I have:

```
word="This is a MixeD cAse stRing"
word_cap=''
for x in word:
        if random.randint(0,1):
                word_cap += x.upper()
        else:
                word_cap += x.lower()
        word = word_cap

print word
```

Im wondering if you could use list comprehension to make it faster.
I couldnt seem to use the lower() and upper() functions in randomchoice
i tried to do something like

```
''.join(randomchoice(x.upper(),x.lower()) for x in word)
```

but i think thats wrong. something like that though is possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import random
s = 'this is a lower case string'

''.join(random.choice((str.upper,str.lower))(x) for x in s)
```

`random.choice` randomly selects one from two functions `str.upper`, `str.lower`.

Then this function is applied to `x` for each letter in the input string `s`.

If initial string has all the letters in lowercase, that I would use this code:

```
''.join(x.upper() if random.randint(0,1) else x for x in s)
```

because the initial code would use redundant `str.lowercase` on half of the letters in the case of lowercase initial string.

By the way, look at the other answer by Michael J. Barber. Python have hefty charges for function calls. In his code he calls `str.upper` only once. In my code `str.upper` is called for about half the symbols of the initial string.  So still a temporary upper-cased string is created in memory, the time efficiency of his code may be much greater.

---

## Lo and behold:

Code timing comparisons: https://ideone.com/eLygn

Comment: Why call `str.lower()` on a string that already is lowercase?

Comment: @TimPietzcker because initial string may have letters in upper case

Comment: @colonwq: I'm betting that this is far from the fastest method. Michael's solution (modified to handle mixed-case strings, which were not part of your question) will certainly be faster, especially with longer strings. I'm not at my home PC right now, so I can't test it, though.

Comment: @ovgolovin While I think clarity is more important than speed here, could you also try Tim's suggestion with the `random.choice` brought into the local namespace? And I suppose for completeness that `''.join(numpy.where(numpy.random.randint(2, size=len(caps)), list(caps), list(lowers)))` would be worth checking, if we completely want to give up on readability in favor of speed.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber I have already tried `random.choice`. But I didn't put `random.choice` into local namespace. I'll update the testing code in a few minutes.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber I updated the testing. Putting `random.choice` into local namespace hasn't increased the efficiency dramatically. But using `random.choice` instead of `x[random.randint(0,1)]` increased efficiency twice.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
word="this is a lower case string"
caps = word.upper()
''.join(x[random.randint(0,1)] for x in zip(word, caps))
```

This should outperform your version because it makes many fewer calls to `upper` and because, more importantly, it avoids the O(N^2) successive appends you used in the version with the loops.

With the modification to the question, you'll need to create both the lowercase and uppercase versions:

```
word="This is a MixeD cAse stRing"
caps = word.upper()
lowers = word.lower()
''.join(random.choice(x) for x in zip(caps, lowers))
```

As suggested by Tim Pietzcker in the comments, I've used `random.choice` to select the letters from the tuples created by the `zip` call.

Since the question has been changed to focus more on speed, the fastest approach is likely to be using Numpy:

```
''.join(numpy.where(numpy.random.randint(2, size=len(caps)), list(caps), list(lowers)))
```

Comment: +1, but `random.choice(x) for x in zip(...)` would look nicer IMO.

Comment: yeh i didnt mention mixed case, sorry. this looks faster, thanks. updated my question.

Comment: I added timing comparisons to the answer. @TimPietzcker

Comment: Using `random.choice(x)` instead of `x[random.randint(0,1)]` makes the code 2 times faster. Why is that?

Comment: @TimPietzcker Yes, I suppose it would look nicer. I'll add it, and update for the mixed case possibility.

Comment: @TimPietzcker The variant with `numpy` was the fastest (35% faster than with `random.choice`). I can't put it on the ideone since there is no `numpy` there.

Comment: By the way, one conversion to `list` may be avoided: `...list(caps), lowers...` or `...caps, list(lowers)` can be used.

Comment: numpy!??? at first i thought that was a reference to me :) wow this has come on since i last looked, now ill have to update my code again! thanks to all, interesting stuff.

Comment: @colonwq Here is the link to the Python script for the functions including that which uses `numpy`: http://www.ideone.com/27Xcc

Comment: top man, thanks! so this website runs code for time comparisons ?